# CSS in a iFrame: it shows CSS code instead of loading and applying it

Tags: php, css, iframe, load, plaintext

I have an iFrame on a PHP page that in some cases and in just some browsers in some machines, instead of loading the CSS normally and aplying the style over the iFrame contents, it just shows the CSS code in a plain text mode.

Does anyone know why this could be possible?

Normal way should be, PHP page loading the iframe, this last one loading the content normally and everything appearing beautifully styled inside this iFrame. But as I said, in Chrome in a machine from a specific user (and just him) it doesn't work this way. Instead of this, we see the CSS code inside the iframe when PHP page finishes loading.

Comment: Could you please add your code

Comment: Which browsers and which machines?

Comment: Talking about Windows machine with Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check the headers that are being sent on the iframe's http request, specifically the "Content-Type" header. In some cases, a document that is served as `text/plain` will not render properly as HTML and CSS. Instead, you will just see the raw code.

This can also happen if your web server is not parsing the file as PHP, but just a plain text file. For example, try renaming a `.php` script to `.myphp` and then visit the URL in your browser. You will probably see the PHP source code and maybe even unprocessed HTML and CSS.